# Angular ng-include is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have trying to use ng-include to create some partial layouts for pop-up's in my web app. However, for some reason I do not see the HTML getting rendered when I execute the include. Here is my HTML after my Overlay Service adds the ngInclude

```
<div id="cover" class="" ng-include="'/Angular/views/gears.html'"></div>
```

And this resides inside of my `ng-app` and my `ng-controller`, so I cannot figure out why my view, `/Angular/views/gears.html` is not showing up correctly?

I made sure that going to `/Angular/views/gears.html` in the browser does in fact serve the correct HTML. It does

**EDIT**

I just realized that placing the above HTML directly into the page renders the correct HTML, however, I am trying to add the include dynamically using a Service, so I think it is not rendering the `ng-include` correctly

**My Overlay Service**

```
app.factory('overlayService', [function () {

        var overlay = {};
        var _cover;
        var _innerContent;

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            _cover = jQuery(document.createElement('div')).attr({ 'id': 'cover', 'ng-include' :''}).prependTo(jQuery('#mainContent'));
        });


        overlay.show = function (templateUrl) {
                jQuery(_cover).addClass('show');

                jQuery('html,body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

                //_cover.attr('ng-include', "'/Angular/views/"+templateUrl+"'");
                overlay.url = templateUrl;

                return _cover;
            }


          overlay.destroy = function () {
                    jQuery('html,body').unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
                    jQuery(_cover).removeClass('show');

                }

          return overlay;

    }]);
```

Comment: Add dynamically using a service? What does that mean? Show more code!

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are attaching the `ng-include` attribute to your div dynamically?

Comment: @JonathanWilson yes exactly, I am not sure if that is the correct way to do it tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dynamically attaching an `ng-include` directive to your element, attach that directive to your div directly in your markup and then show/hide with `ng-if`:

```
<div 
    ng-if="myService.someBoolCheck('cover')" 
    ng-include="'/Angular/views/gears.html'"></div>
```

Alternatively, just create an element within your overlayService and append it to the DOM with angular's built-in [`$document` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24document).  I'm assuming there is one and only one overlay element used in your application and that it is controlled solely by your overlay service.

Comment: So I tried to do that but I cannot see whats happening to the `div` because Angular has taken it out of the DOM and replaced it with `<!-- nInclude: overlay.url-->`

Comment: if you see a comment in the `div`'s place, that's because the div has been removed from the DOM.  This means the boolean being passed to `ng-if` is `false`.  Switch from `ng-if` to `ng-show` if you want still want to be able to inspect the hidden `div`.

Comment: Except I never added your ng-if yet.. I still simply have `<div id="cover" ng-include="overlay.url"></div>` in the DOM, and in my controller I have an `overlay` service that has a `url` attribute that gets modified when `overlay.show(url)` is called

Comment: Oh, ok.  So I assume in your controller, you doing something like this: `function($scope,overlayService){ $scope.overlay = overlayService; }`. Right?

Comment: yes, I have that and it still doesn't render, just shows a comment

Comment: Oh I just got it, it was a combination of not assigning the service into the actual $scope and not assigning the correct URL once I changed the way I added the ng-include

Comment: I see that `overlay.url` is initially undefined.  Try setting `overlay.url=""` somewhere in your service.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving an absolute path : /Angular/views/gears.html .
 Try typing only views/gears.html if views is at the same level as your index.html page.
 Take a look at your network tab ( chrome console, firebug or any other) in order to
see if your template is being loaded with an Ajax request.

Comment: As I said in my edit, I can get the functionality to work if I manual place the `<div id="cover">` in the HTML. But I want it to be dynamically added